# this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))); means what

Tags: angular, typescript, function, rxjs

I am trying to break down this single piece of code snippet to understand.  new BehaviourSubject seems to be a function call. But what is  have to do there.Is it asking the function BehaviourSubject  to have a return type User.Please explain to me this in an understandable manner.

```
this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` requires an initial value and emits the current value to new subscribers. The initial value comes from `localStorage`. That's it.
You can add subscribers to `this.userSubject` to get the initial value later.

`new BehaviorSubject<User>`, the angle brackets `<>` means `BehaviorSubject` is a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes) and `User` passed in is a generic type parameter.

Here is an example:

```js
// RxJS v6+
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(123);

// two new subscribers will get initial value => output: 123, 123
subject.subscribe(console.log);
subject.subscribe(console.log);

// two subscribers will get new value => output: 456, 456
subject.next(456);

// new subscriber will get latest value (456) => output: 456
subject.subscribe(console.log);

// all three subscribers will get new value => output: 789, 789, 789
subject.next(789);

// output: 123, 123, 456, 456, 456, 789, 789, 789
```

Comment: A big thanks for trying to help me.Can you please tell me what does <> mean and what has it got to do with the code

Comment: thanks now i got it.I am so much greatful to you

Comment: @somanraj Glad to help. If it helps you, please mark it as an answer.